# what is pr, pi, abr, abi in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm new to Kubernetes, i have been assigned with task to write a script in which i see there are number of commands like 'kubectl get pr -A', 'kubectl get pi -A', 'kubeclt get abr -A', 'kubectl get abi -A'. on asking about the what is pr, pi, abr, abi-- requester just replied its pi-> profileInstallation, pr-->ProfileRegistration, abi->AppBundleInstallation and abr ->AppBundleRegistration.

Can anybody help me understand what this ProfileInstallation, ProfileRegistration, AppBundleInstallation and AppBundleRegistration are?

I'm just trying to understand are they regular kubernetes object or its custom objects?

Comment: The [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/) reference lists all of the standard objects; the ones you list aren't among those.

Comment: The "teach to fish" version is `kubectl api-resources | grep abr` (or, of course, without the "grep") shows every resource type known by the current-context's cluster; there are `-o json` and `-o yaml` if those are easier to parse in your circumstance

Comment: @mdaniel: on trying with the command, i got the below error:

kubectl api-resource | grep abr
Error: unknown command "api-resource" for "kubectl"

Did you mean this?
        api-resources

Run 'kubectl --help' for usage.

Comment: @DavidMaze: what these can be (pi, pr, abi, abr)??.. can you help me with any document if we create these non-standard object, how to use.